Calling C functions from Nasm X86_64 Assembly
I'm trying to dynamically link a shared library with my nasm program for a compiler I'm making
This is my nasm program
main.asm
SYS_EXIT equ 60

extern print_thingy

%macro exit 1 ; 1 -> takes one argument
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, %1
    syscall
%endmacro

section .text
    global _start

_start: 
    call print_thingy

    mov rax, 0
    exit rax


Here's my simple C program that I compile to a shared object using
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libshared.so shared.c

shared.c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_thingy() {
    printf("Thingy\n");
}

I first build my C program and create a shared object out of it using
gcc -fPIC -rdynamic -shared -o libshared.so shared.c

Then I build my Nasm program using
nasm -g -F dwarf -f elf64 main.asm -o main.o;

Then I link using
ld -o main main.o -lshared -L.

Now, when I try to run the program using ./main I get zsh: no such file or directory: ./main
I checked and ./main has all necessary premissions
$ file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld64.so.1, with debug_info, not stripped

$ ls -lah main
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pragyan pragyan 14K Aug 24 14:49 main

Checked inside the shared object libshared.so and my function is present
$ objdump -T libshared.so

libshared.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000  Base        _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) puts
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000  Base        __gmon_start__
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000  Base        _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) __cxa_finalize
0000000000001109 g    DF .text  0000000000000016  Base        print_thingy


When I do ldd main it shows
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeeb18e000)
        libshared.so => not found


so I put libshared.so inside /usr/local/lib ran sudo ldconfig and tried all the steps again, but still ldd main can't find libshared.so
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is also properly set
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:


ld's default for the ELF interpreter path is normally not what you need on modern systems.  Does /lib/ld64.so.1 exist on your system?  Probably not, but file showed you that's the path it'll look for.  When it's not found, the execve system call itself will return -ENOENT.  Either link with GCC -nostdlib or use the right path with an ld option.

Also, don't mix printf with a raw _exit system call.  You'll exit without flushing the stdio buffer, so your output will be empty when stdout isn't a TTY so it's full-buffered.  call exit from libc, which your shared library depends on so you might as well have your main program also depend on it.

So, does the interpreter being /lib/ld64.so.1 instead of /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, which I see is the case for a binary compiled by gcc, mean that I messed up in the linking step? Afaik, the linker used by gcc is also ld. -nostdlib doesn't work as it can't find puts. Thanks for the heads up about io buffering

gcc passes the correct option to ld. As Peter said, for whatever reason, the default of ld is not suitable for most systems. If -nostdlib does not find puts that means you put it on the wrong command. You likely used it for the shared library instead of the executable. You need to use gcc -nostdlib instead of the ld. The other gcc for the shared lib is fine.

So I looked into what gcc was doing, and turns out it's using a different linker. When I passed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 to ld and then linked, it worked.
